# How do I correctly display the position/duration of a MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, time, formatting, media-player

Hi 
I want to display player position and player duration in simple date format. that is. `00:00:01/00:00:06`. The first part is current position of the player and the second part is the duration. 
I have used `SimpleDateFormat` to try display the duration and position in this format, but it is showing me the output as `05:30:00/05:30:06`.

Here is the code I am using:

```
time1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
currentTime.setText("" + time1.format(player.getCurrentPosition());
```

How do I print out the position and duration correctly? (It is displaying hours/minutes that should not be there).

Kindly help me out, Swathi Daruri.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`DateFormat` works for dates, not for time intervals. So if you get a position of 1 second, the DateFormat interprets this as meaning that the date/time is 1 second after the beginning the calendar (which is January 1st, 1970).

You'd need to do something like

```
private String getTimeString(long millis) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

    int hours = (int) (millis / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    int minutes = (int) ((millis % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    int seconds = (int) (((millis % (1000 * 60 * 60)) % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    buf
        .append(String.format("%02d", hours))
        .append(":")
        .append(String.format("%02d", minutes))
        .append(":")
        .append(String.format("%02d", seconds));

    return buf.toString();
}
```

And then do something like

```
totalTime.setText(getTimeString(duration));
currentTime.setText(getTimeString(position));
```

Comment: thank u so much.. it worked. i thought i can make it through simple date format

Comment: You need to cast the Integers `int hours = (int) (millis / (1000*60*60));`

Comment: such day saving logic

Comment: This helps. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

just try this one

```
fun getDurationString(durationMs: Long, negativePrefix: Boolean): String {
    val hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(durationMs)
    val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(durationMs)
    val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(durationMs)

    return if (hours > 0) {
        format(
            Locale.getDefault(), "%s%02d:%02d:%02d",
            if (negativePrefix) "- " else "",
            hours,
            minutes - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hours),
            seconds - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(minutes)
        )
    } else format(
        Locale.getDefault(), "%s%02d:%02d",
        if (negativePrefix) "- " else "",
        minutes,
        seconds - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(minutes)
    )
}
```