# show time when song is playing in android

Tags: android, media-player

i am trying to play a song by using MediaPlayer from the given list.i want include time duration for the song from starting to ending of the song. how to add time and how to update that time from 0:00 to till the end of that song

Comment: Please refer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548922/how-do-i-correctly-display-the-position-duration-of-a-mediaplayer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the method `getCurrentPosition()` which gives you the current position in milliseconds.

You can also use the method `getDuration()` to get the full length of the song.

You can use a separate thread to update the timer.

Answer (score 14):

To show the playing time, I've used [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html), which updates `TextView tv` every 1000ms. Note that not using [tv.post(Runnable action)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for setting text in Text View would not block the UI thread and may cause problems.

```
if (player != null) {
    player.start();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (player != null && player.isPlaying()) {
                        tv.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                tv.setText(player.getCurrentPosition());
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        timer.cancel();
                        timer.purge();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}
```