# trigger function when sound reach certain position

Tags: android, audio

i want to play sound either using mediaplayer or sound pool. and i want to do something when my sound/music reach some position such as

```
function void hello(){ // you reach position 1.5 seconds }  

mediaplayer.setOnCertainPosition(1500, hello()); // not actual code
```

currently what i found is create loop function for every xxx millisecond and do

```
mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition()
```

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20543679/1334052)

is there any better code?
note: i found about [audiotrack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener(android.media.AudioTrack.OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener)) but not sure how it works and how to use it

Comment: If I was doing this I would use a timer that starts the same time of the media player, that would fire ontick every 1.5 second. Whether that is the a better solution is another question

Comment: If you don't want to set a timer, you could just check the volume when the volume changes by setting an observer, as specified in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896746/is-there-a-broadcast-action-for-volume-changes

Comment: @Phil3992 my trigger time is not "every xx seconds" but at certain time like 1s, 9s, 15s, etc.. TheManHasNoName the trigger from timer not volume, but its like that code implement broadcasting when something happen on audio manager