# how to display the duration of my song?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I would like to display the duration of the song.

```
public class Songs extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer song;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_surah);
        song=MediaPlayer.create(Songs.this,R.raw.song);
    }
    public void play1(View v){
        song.start();
    }
    public void pause1(View v){
        song.pause();
    }
}
```

Comment: this answer may be useful [ https://stackoverflow.com/a/20543679/5919568 ]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Timer` which will be updated every 1000 milliseconds. Then set time to a `TextView` or what ever you want.

```
song.start();
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (song != null && song.isPlaying()) {
                    tv.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tv.setText(song.getCurrentPosition());
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    timer.cancel();
                    timer.purge();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}, 0, 1000);
```