# how to update audio progress to minutes

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, textview, android-seekbar

currently in my app the media plays correctly and the textView also updates perfectly.. in seconds 0:00

below is the code for `onProgressChanged`

```
@Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {
            seekBarHint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            int x = (int) Math.ceil(progress / 1000f);

            if (x < 10)
                seekBarHint.setText("0:0" + x);
            if (x > 10)
                seekBarHint.setText("0:" + x);
            }
```

the above code is working as it should..

i want the textView timer to update to 1:00 after it plays for 0:59 seconds

i tried to update the code as below :

```
@Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {
        seekBarHint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        int x = (int) Math.ceil(progress / 1000f);

        if (x < 10)
            seekBarHint.setText("0:0" + x);
        if (x > 10)
            seekBarHint.setText("0:" + x);

    if (x >= 60 &&  x < 70)
           x=0;
           seekBarHint.setText("1:0" + x);
    if (x > 70)
           seekBarHint.setText("1:" + x);
}
```

but i get the textView as `"1.00"` from the start. and after 0.59 seconds.. it shows as `1:060` `1:061` and so on...

**How to update the value of `x` to 0 after the media plays for 0.59 seconds..**

in short

i am getting the textView value as

> 0:00 to 0:59    then 0:60 ...

i want it as

> 0:00 to 0:59   then 1:00

Comment: read `android.text.format.DateUtils` documentation

Comment: @pskink .. i have asked the question as i am not able to understand the concept.. if only you could make it simpler rather than just advicing.. it would be great...

Comment: so did you check the official documentation?

Comment: yes.. could you simplify as per my requirement.. if you could explain what changes to be made..

Comment: ok so what problems do you have after reading the documentation? whats unclear?

Comment: how to implement `formatElapsedTime` when an audio is playing?

Comment: you dont have to implement anything -  just pass the time parameter: `"elapsedSeconds long: the elapsed time in seconds."`

Comment: my problem is solved... i refered here .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548922/how-do-i-correctly-display-the-position-duration-of-a-mediaplayer

Comment: no, this is a wrong solution, what don't you simply use formatElapsedTime?

Comment: @pskink .. thank you .. i'll try and revert back..

Comment: thanks a lot @pskink .. i used the following code to solve my problem... `String timer = DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(Long.valueOf((mpos/1000)));
tv1.setText(timer);
`

Comment: hope this is the right method.. isn't it @pskink

Comment: what do you need `Long.valueOf` for? if `mpos` is a long value then simply use `DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(mpos/1000)`

Comment: yes.. correct... thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `x` is time in seconds, then this simple line should work.

```
seekBarHint.setText(String.format(secondsToString(x))

private String secondsToString(int pTime) {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d", pTime / 60, pTime % 60);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the simplified version of the code.... i've edited my answer below....

Answer (score 0):

with the suggestions by [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) in the comments above and [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils#formatElapsedTime(long)) link reference..

i update my code as below which worked for me:

```
public void SeekUpdation() {

if(mediaPlayer!=null) {
int mpos = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
mHandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
int seconds = (mpos / 1000);
timerTextView.setText(String.format(secondsToString(seconds)));
}
```

Hope this might help someone...